# android java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm stuck with this error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

My code:

```
String[] web = new String[jsonArray.length()-1];
int[] imageId = new int[]{jsonArray.length()-1};
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
    jo_inside = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    imageId[i] = R.drawable.a1;
    web[i] = jo_inside.getString("level");
}
```

Comment: Use breakpoints and step through the code. You will see when you get the error and it will narrow the problems down

Comment: @ Rotwang Also tried this error remains same

Comment: You are making Array with (length-1) and then you are accesing web[length] element which is out of bonds

Comment: Tried what? That posts tells you that you are accessing an array outside it's length.